# How to access a local structure pointer in a different directory in c?

Tags: c

I am using C as programming language and Linux as a platform, and I can't change my toolchain.
I have a structure in common header file.

```
struct bh_shaper_profile_table_t{
        u64 shaper_profile;
        u64 node_idx;
};

struct bh_shaper_profile_tblx_t{
        struct bh_shaper_profile_table_t shaper_pair[250];
        size_t count;
};
```

and a function which allocates memory for the above structure

```
struct bh_shaper_profile_tblx_t* newShpMap()
{
    struct bh_shaper_profile_tblx_t* ret = calloc(1, sizeof (*ret));
    ret->count = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

Now in file1.c I have function which populated the above mentioned structure

```
int fillmap(){
    struct bh_shaper_profile_tblx_t *b_shp_map = newShpMap();
    .........................

}
```

Now I need to access the b_shp_map in file2.c which is in different directory. I can't make the b_shp_map as global variable as C won't allow me to non-constant initialisation.

In file2.c I have a function

```
void setup(struct shaper_cfg_t *fl_shaper_config){
    ..................
    struct update_shaper *mp;
    /* Logic check if the node index pass via fl_shaper_config matched or not */
    ...........
    mp->shp_prof = b_shp_map->shaper_profile;
    /* Fill other member variable */

   shaper_params_update_t(&mp);

}
```

The setup call is via different caller and not directly called from file1.c's any function, they are different node basically. file1.c populates data at boot-up time and file2.c function updated in run-time. So directly passing the structure pointer not possible.

I tried to put the entire mem allocation function in the header file itself but getting a linking error.

Any idea or a different approach is highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Niladri

Comment: Please show a [mre], especially _how_ file2.c needs to access that structure, and how both files are "connected".

Comment: Pass the variable while calling the function.

Comment: "Different directory"- C doesn't care at all about directory structures.

Comment: i would suggest putting the entire allocation function to the header file, but you said that you had a linking error, you should try to both declare and define the function in the header file

Comment: How about `int fillMap(struct bh_shaper_profile_tblx_t **ret_shp_map) {` `...` `*ret_shp_map = b_shp_map;` `...` `}`?